# How do you configure VS2013 webtest Load Test project to include a directory for Unit Test objects?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2013, load-testing

I have been trying to include files and directories in my Load Test project using Visual Studio 2013 webtests.

I am stuck on getting the directories in the proper location and creating a directory where the assemblies that I am testing log request/responses.

I have been able to decorate the Class and/or TestMethods to the following:

```
[DeploymentItem("\\SharedFiles\\Configuration" , ".\\Configuration")]
```

This will place the files and create a directory in the folder:

```
D:\Test Projects\WebLoadTest\TestResults\DEV_UNITLOADTEST\Out\Configuration\
```

My main issue is that the assembly the method to get the current directory of the application at runtime:

```
Path.GetDirectoryName((new System.Uri(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase)).LocalPath)
```

I then log to a new text file at that location with "\Configuration"

I have also added the following to the Post Build Events of the project.

```
XCOPY /Y /S "$(ProjectDir)Configuration\*" "$(TargetDir)\Configuration\"
```

This does not seem to help with the issue.  I am getting an Error from XCOPY #4.

If I am quick and can get a copy of the directory made during the load test initialization, the tests will work.  So I copy the directories directly into the Test Project's deployment location:

```
D:\Test Projects\WebLoadTest\TestResults\DEV_UNITLOADTEST
```

Creating the directory manually immediately after starting the Load Test:

```
D:\Test Projects\WebLoadTest\TestResults\DEV_UNITLOADTEST\Configuration
```

Is there a way to automate this and have Visual Studio create this location for me?

Comment: The `.testsettings` files have a section for deploying files and directories.

Comment: I have been using the .testsettings and .remotesettings but it will not deploy to the root, only the created directory root for the test.  The assembly needs to have the directory deployed to the root and not the test directory root, basically the parent directory of the test project.